# How to drop input channels or neurons at the inference phase

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, convolutional-neural-network

I understand that dropout is used to drop some weights during training, is there a way one can conventionally train a neural network with full weights and then drop some weights at the inference?

My understanding is that during testing, for instance using MNIST data-sets, the test accuracy is computed as:

```
test_accuracy = accuracy.eval ({X: mnist.test.images, Y: mnist.test.labels})
```

How can I modify the code so that some weights are set to zero?

Comment: Why would you want to drop input information when inferring? You would be diminishing the potential of your net! Dropout during training has the purpose of preventing overfitting - a problem that is specific to the training phase.

Comment: @Neuneck A reason you may wish to have dropout during your inference phase is that it may give you a measure of your model's uncertainty.  https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.02142